# Starting a new activity from a subclass with a listener

Tags: android, android-activity, dictionary, android-intent

In order to detect map movements and gestures and use the lazy loading support for my map items I'm trying to work with this library: http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/.

I've setup a map attached the overlayManager and the events are coming through just fine. I can throw a toast from the listener just fine. When I get Application context it is not null.

I'm stuck trying to launch an intent from the ManagedOverlay class. Specifically in the `onDoubleTap` method below I'm trying to launch an intent and I get this error message:

```
 Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
```

I think I generally understand that I need to call back to the MapActivity subclass and have it launch the intent or I need to do something with the context differently. I'm having trouble ironing out the specifics however. Any assistance appreciated.

```
public class SiteMapRev2 extends MapActivity {

    private MapView mapView;
    private OverlayManager overlayManager;
    private MapController mapController;
    private MyLocationOverlay userLocationOverlay;
    private ArrayList<SiteSummary> sitesRoster = null;
    private Drawable siteIcon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);      
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        overlayManager = new OverlayManager(this, mapView);

        sitesRoster = new ArrayList<SiteSummary>(); 
        userLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);

        mapView.getOverlays().add(userLocationOverlay);
        mapController = mapView.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(14);
        siteIcon = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);

    }



    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Drawable defaultmarker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2);

        ManagedOverlay managedOverlay = overlayManager.createOverlay("sites", defaultmarker);

        managedOverlay.setOnOverlayGestureListener(new ManagedOverlayGestureDetector.OnOverlayGestureListener(){

            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0, ManagedOverlay arg1,
                    GeoPoint arg2, ManagedOverlayItem arg3) {

                if (arg3 == null) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    **SiteOverlayItem thisItem = (SiteOverlayItem) arg3;
                    String siteIDAsString = Integer.toString(thisItem.getSiteID());
                    Context c = getApplicationContext();
                    Intent showSiteDetails = new Intent(c,SiteDetailActivity.class);
                    Log.d(toString(), "intent = " + showSiteDetails.toString());
                    showSiteDetails.setData(Uri.parse(siteIDAsString));
                    c.startActivity(showSiteDetails);
                    return true;**
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the application context, I would do this:

```
SiteMapRev2.this.startActivity(showSiteDetails);
```

which starts the activity from your map activity as you normally would.

Answer (score 1):

Set this Flag to your intent, Logcat is too smart, try to understand what is says to you ;)

```
showSiteDetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Comment: This will lose the navigation back stack though correct? I should have noted this in my question but preserving the back stack is neccessary for my UI scenario.

Comment: Then don't use Application context, just use the context of your current Activity. If this not works, then your logic is not correct.